# Kafka Producer fails when one of brokers unreachable on network

Tags: .net, apache-kafka

I have kafka cluster of 3 brokers and zookeeper. My application (.NET) run in kubernetes cluster and uses this kafka. At some moment one of broker become unreachable from kubernetes cluster due to network problems. This cause application produce problems, it gets errors `Local: Message timed out` and can't produce to kafka at all. Network problems was only between kubernetes cluster and broker, so kafka was totally fine.

Is there anything I can do about this situation to make application works?

According to producer page - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/producer.html

> producer sends a produce request to the leader of that partition

so mayne it's expected that if leader is unreachable, nothing will work. But I assume that application can still send produce requests to other available brokers.

Answer (score 0):

To see the pod logs you can use this command:

```
(kubectl logs podname -n your namespace )
```

And to check your Kubernetes network use this command:

```
(kubectl get pod -n kube-system )
```

If you have any issues in your network you can find them by using this commands.

Comment: I want to understand can I do something with kafka setup to handle such situation.
Fixing network issues is out of my question scope

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).